# Updating code to save the state of the clicked items

Tags: android

I'm a new developer to android development. I'll like the code below (for querying and displaying images media collection) whose images checkboxes are checked when clicked, to be updated to include onsaveinstancestate to save the state of the clicked/checked items.

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<ImageModel > imageList;
    RecyclerView imageRecyclerView;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    View view;
 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
        runtimePermission();
    
        return view;
    }
 
    private void runtimePermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(getContext()).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        init();
                        getAllImages();
                        setImageList();
 
                    }
 
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission is Required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
 
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
 
    public void init() {
        imageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.photos_recycler);
        imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
 
    public void setImageList() {
        imageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager((new  GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4)));
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext(), imageList);
        imageRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        /* Here `isSelected` is a boolean variable. It is true when item is checked and false when not checked. When false, the if condition evaluates to true and the `selectImage()` method is called, otherwise the `unSelectImage()` is called */

        imageAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemViewClick(int position, View v){
                try {
                    if (!imageList.get(position).isSelected) {
                        selectImage(position);
                    } else {
                        unSelectImage(position);
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ed) {
                    ed.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    };

    public void selectImage(int position) {
        imageList.get(position).setSelected(true);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void unSelectImage(int position) {
        imageList.get(position).setSelected(false);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Querying the mediastore for images collection

```
public void getAllImages() {
    Uri imageCollection;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        imageCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    } else {
        imageCollection = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE
    };

    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(imageCollection , projection, null, null, sortOrder);
    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
    int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
        String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
        int duration = cursor.getInt(dateColumn);
        int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);
        Uri uriImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(imageCollection, ""+ id);
        ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
        imageModel.setImage(uriImage);
        imageList.add(imageModel);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Do your checkboxes keep checked if you scroll the items up and down and out of sight?

Comment: @blackapps: I use a tab layout and the checkable items are contained in one of them. While they keep checked even when scrolling the items,they loose their checked state upon swiping to a different layout and back.

Comment: What did you do to keep the state while scrolling?

Comment: I did nothing special. The selected checkboxs remained checked even while scrolling

Comment: `imageList.get(position).setSelected(true);` Somewhere in your `ImageModel` you can save the state and read the state. Then if your list is destroyed do save these states and use when you recreate the list as that is what apparently occurs. getAllImages is called again then i think.